# how to get all special characters typed by user in edit text in android

Tags: java, android, special-characters, android-edittext

Hey guys
i have edit text in my application

User can type any of the special characters like @#$%^&* and obviously make smileys

I have to post this message to server by appending the messsage in url

but i have exp that # and & are not recognised

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [URLEncoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html) to encode your string before attaching to the url.